# Ajax call to a django view is returning an array of strings

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am new django and ajax and i am trying to send a post request to django view when a user clicks on a button in my html page. The django view has to return a json object when I tried to do that it gives me an error saying

`TypeError: Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable`

How can we send an Object type  serializable in django.

Manage_project.html

```
<form action="{% url 'supervisor:manageproject' %}" id="my_form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="project_id", value={{project.id}}>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="projectName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Project Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="project" class="form-control-plaintext" id="projectName" value="{{project.project_name}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h6>Manage the employees list:</h6>
    <p>Check the boxes to remove employees:</p>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <table class="table">
            {% for employee in employees_could_add.all %}
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees_inproject" value="{{employee.id}}"> {{employee}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor%}
            <tr>
              <td><button class="btn btn-primary" name="perform" value = "Add" type="submit">Add Employees</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <table class="table">
          {% for employee in project.employees.all %}
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="employees" value="{{employee.id}}"> {{employee}}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor%}
          <tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" name="perform" value="delete" type="submit">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

ajaxcalls.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("hi")
   $('#my_form').submit(function(e) { // catch the form's submit event
  // e.preventDefault()
      //console.log($(this))
       $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
           data: $(this).serialize() + '&perform='+$('button').val(), // get the form data
           type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
           dataType: "json",
           url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
           success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                    console.log('error')
                    console.log(data)
             }
       });
       return false;
   }); 
});
```

views.py

```
if request.POST['perform'] == 'Add':
            employee_ids = request.POST.getlist('employees_inproject')
            project_id = request.POST['project_id']
            project = Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)[0]
            for e_id in employee_ids:
                emp = Profile.objects.filter(id=e_id)[0]
                project.employees.add(emp)
            employees = Profile.objects.all()
            employees_inproject =  project.employees.all()
            employees_could_add =  employees.difference(employees_inproject)
            print(1, employees_could_add)
            data = {
                'employees_could_add' : employees_could_add,
                'project' : project
            }
            print(data['employees_could_add'])
            #return JsonResponse( model_to_dict(data) )

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': data}), content_type="application/json")
```

stack trace

```
`[27/Mar/2018 11:41:14] "GET /supervisor/manageproject/?project_id=10&    manage_project=Manage+Project HTTP/1.1" 200 2902
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':     ['Fawz6ZbzuvWyPGGcLqDccOEGWwmZM6TsoBvUenAuEFEkXWkk1Ra6f0d1uvzedV6Z'],  'project_id': ['10'], 'project': ['Project P'], 'employees_inproject': ['10'], 'perform': ['Add']}>
Add
1 <QuerySet [<Profile: uday>, <Profile: sandeep>]>
<QuerySet [<Profile: uday>, <Profile: sandeep>]>
Internal Server Error: /supervisor/manageproject/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32 \lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\team\Desktop\django\TMS_1\TMS_1\TMS\supervisor\views.py", line 131, in manageproject_view
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'data': data}), content_type="application/json")#({'data' : list(data)})
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable
[27/Mar/2018 11:41:16] "POST /supervisor/manageproject/ HTTP/1.1" 500 15895`
```

Edit :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    job_position = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    salary = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.emp_name

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {
    'employees_could_add' : employees_could_add.values(),
    'project' : project.values()
}
```

use this

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.values()` returns a `ValuesQuerySet` object - also not json serializable unless I'm mistaken

Comment: `.values()` returned a `ValuesQuerySet` then indexing it returned a json object which can be serializable